# Pass a sql parameter value to devexpress report?

Tags: c#, webforms, devexpress, report

I want to pass a sql parameter from user form to my report class but it is not working and it does not create the report and when I open the report designer tab again after adding ID argument to the report class it refresh the report and delete my components.

What is the problem?

Here is my report class:

```
public SodoorZemanatName(long ID)
    {
        InitializeComponent(ID);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Designer generated code
    private void InitializeComponent(long ID)
    {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.CustomSqlQuery customSqlQuery1 = new DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.CustomSqlQuery();
            DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.QueryParameter queryParameter1 = new DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.QueryParameter();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(SodoorZemanatName));
            this.topMarginBand1 = new DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.TopMarginBand();
            this.detailBand1 = new DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.DetailBand();
            this.bottomMarginBand1 = new DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.BottomMarginBand();
            this.sqlDataSource2 = new DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlDataSource(this.components);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this)).BeginInit();
            this.topMarginBand1.HeightF = 100F;
            this.topMarginBand1.Name = "topMarginBand1";
            this.detailBand1.HeightF = 100F;
            this.detailBand1.Name = "detailBand1";
            this.bottomMarginBand1.HeightF = 100F;
            this.bottomMarginBand1.Name = "bottomMarginBand1";
            this.sqlDataSource2.ConnectionName = "Context";
            this.sqlDataSource2.Name = "sqlDataSource2";
            customSqlQuery1.Name = "Query";
            queryParameter1.Name = "ID";
            queryParameter1.Type = typeof(long);
            queryParameter1.ValueInfo = "0";
            queryParameter1.Value = ID;
            customSqlQuery1.Parameters.Add(queryParameter1);
            customSqlQuery1.Sql = "select * from LG_Garanti where ID=@ID";
            this.sqlDataSource2.Queries.AddRange(new DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlQuery[] {
            customSqlQuery1});
            this.sqlDataSource2.ResultSchemaSerializable = resources.GetString("sqlDataSource2.ResultSchemaSerializable");
    this.Bands.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.Band[] {
    this.topMarginBand1,
    this.detailBand1,
    this.bottomMarginBand1});
    this.ComponentStorage.AddRange(new System.ComponentModel.IComponent[] {
    this.sqlDataSource2});
    this.DataSource = this.sqlDataSource2;
    this.Version = "15.2";
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this)).EndInit();
}
#endregion
```

And here is my calling:

```
SodoorZemanatName report = new SodoorZemanatName(1);
ASPxDocumentViewer1.ReportTypeName = "SodoorZemanatName";
ASPxDocumentViewer1.Report = report;
```

Comment: I think you need to design the report separately.
 Simply use `new DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport();` may not do because it doesn't know how to use your data source, how to display the data. 

`DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport report = new your_report_design_class();`

I used this kind of thing in the past, I have to create new report with my design before assigning a datasource to it

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to (1) click the button, (2) pass an ID then (3) open the report has content depends on that ID. So this is the way I did it, (I'm not sure is there any other way because devexpress is not open source):

1. Design your dataset, it contains only the info you want to show using the dataset tool of Visual Studio. i.e. id, name, address, ..... Name that dataset = ReportDataset. That dataset has 1 table named MyTable.
2. Design your report named MyReport using the GUI tool (remember to choose XtraReport), and select the datasource = that ReportDataset, do not edit the code generated by the GUI tool. Just use the GUI, click & click to add labels, add value from the ReportDataset.
3. In you form, window form or whatever, the below should be inside the function triggered by button_click event (your "calling" in the last snippet of your question):

   ```
   DataSet new_ds = new DataSet();
   ReportDataset.MyTable runtime_data = new ReportDataset.MyTable();
   //get data from your database according to ID, Row by row 
   //then add them to the runtime_data table
   //in your case, add all the result of "select * from LG_Garanti where ID=@ID";
   runtime_data.Rows.Add(new object[] {.blah blah..});// just add row, use whatever method you like
   new_ds.Tables.Add(runtime_data);
   //from this point, new_ds contains runtime data of the row(s) you want ID.
   //now just link that dynamic dataset to your designed report
   MyReport my_report = new MyReport();
   my_report.DataSource = new_ds;
   // Show the print preview or do whatever you want 
   ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(my_report);
   printTool.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
   ```

The above is to make it more flexible since the report can use its own dataset with the mixture of different tables,.... You can make it easier by reuse your own dataset in step 1. Hope this helps.

Comment: In my code behind I cant access ReportDataset cause I have created it in report designer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, create the data source outside then assign it to your report (using the .xsd file), I don't have access to Visual Studio now so I can't say.
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4797

Comment: Create the dataset and save it as .xsd file like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171897.aspx

Comment: I think he want these:https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument5210 and https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument17387